# Get Average Salary for each employee

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I started learning PL/SQL a few days ago from scratch (NO SQL background) and now I'm trying to play with aggregate functions and was attempting to get the **average salary for each employee.**

Table would look like this:

Table 1:

[image]

And I'd like to see this:

Table 2:

[image]

At the moment, I'm doing something like this:

```
SELECT
  employee, AVG(salary)
FROM
  employees

GROUP BY employee, salary
```

But it's giving the a result identical to table 1.

In other words, I'd like to learn how to consolidate or aggregate a number of rows into a single one. Basically, calculate the average salary for each employee and display just one row with the employee and it's respective AVG(SALARY).

Is this not possible or am I just doing something wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Will do next time, @JuanCarlosOropeza! Sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: Just remove salary column from group by

```
 SELECT employee, AVG(salary) FROM employees
   GROUP BY employee
```

Comment: YES!! Thank you so much! I know this was probably the dumbest question you've ever seen. I appreciate you for helping me out! :) Marking your reply as answer!

Answer (score 1):

This is super awkward for me, but I won't delete the question just in case someone runs into the same issue as me.

Error was in the `group by`, I should have grouped only by `employee`.

For some reason, I thought I had to group by every column that was present in the `SELECT`.

So, query should be:

```
SELECT
    employee, AVG(salary)
FROM
    employees  
GROUP BY 
    employee -- ERROR WAS HERE, leave just employee. -.-
```

I'm sorry for not noticing a before, rookie mistake.

Comment: You dont need add this. the selected answer already explain it.